# Add in Hash and update DOM element dynamically using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, dom, hash, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have hash of users as the following:

```
{"A1": {name: "Demo-1", status: "active"}, "A2": {name: "Demo-2", status: "deactive"}};
```

And I have two hashes of active/deactive users, and I make the table of each of them as the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id, user) in deactiveUsers">
      <td>
        {{ user.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" ng-click="change(id)">Active</button>
      </td>

</tr>
```

And If I click on `Active` button, I remove the object from `deactiveUsers`, and add it in `activeUsers`, the `change` function as the following:

```
$scope.change = function(id){
 if($scope.users[id].status == "active"){
   delete $scope.activeUsers[id];
   $scope.users[id].status = "deactive";
   $scope.deactiveUsers[id] = $scope.users[id];
 }else{
   delete $scope.deactiveUsers[id];
   $scope.users[id].status = "active";
   $scope.activeUsers[id] = $scope.users[id];

 }
}
```

This my [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WDOvzuCIrxUPED1yOWgq?p=preview), it's working well if I tried it on plnkr. But on my localhost the deleting only is working, when I add on `activeUsers` the DOM element doesn't update with the new record.

I can't find out the issue.

1. How can I add in Hash to update the DOM element dynamically ?
2. why it's working on plnkr, but the same code doesn't work on localhost ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in Dev Tools console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple body tags in your DOM. I think the first  (after the first table element) cause the others angular directives are outside the app.
Replace the body in your table elements by tbody elements.

**Edit By the question's owner**

My Error was I developed the tables as the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <table></table>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

So, I called `ng-controller` twice, I fixed it by develop one div for the both as the following:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <table></table>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <table></table>
  </div>
</div>
```